# Maven сборка проекта

Tags: java, maven

У меня есть 2 проекта собранных на maven. Оба проекта имеют одинаковый groupId, соответственно разные artefactId

Вот так выглядит pom файл

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
<artifactId>server_app</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>myWorkApp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Проблема в том, что в проекте server_app я вижу классы и методы из myWorkApp, имеющие видимость default (т.е. внутри пакета), мне нужно чтобы я из server_app не имел доступа к таким классам и методам из myWorkApp, не делая их private. Можно это сделать не меняя groupId у одного из проектов?

Comment: Посмотрите информацию про модули https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/java-9-moduli-project-jigsaw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
```

не влияет на видимость классов и методов в них, это способ однозначно идентифицировать зависимость, объединить их в группы
На видимость влияет значение package в классах
Если в приложении myWorkApp в классе Clazz в котором

```
package com.example
```

есть метод например

```
void test() {...}
```

и в приложении server_app есть класс в котором тоже указан

```
package com.example
```

то в его методах будет доступен метод Clazz#test.
Чтобы не видеть такие методы, просто используй свой package на уровень глубже
в server_app

```
com.example.server
```

в myWorkApp

```
com.example.mywork
```